# Eigenstates of angular momentum with circular symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, symmetry, schroedinger-equation

Suppose I am solving the the 2D Schrödinger equation for a problem with [circular symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_symmetry). In this case my intuition tells me that the solutions should be common eigenfunctions of $L^2_{\perp} = L_{x}^2 + L_{y}^2$ and $L_{z}$. Is there an easy way to know the form of these and their degeneracy?

In the 3D case with spherical symmetry, for example, one would simply have that they were common eigenfunctions of $L^2 = L_{x}^2 + L_{y}^2 + L_{z}^2$ and $L_{z}$, which are labeled by the quantum numbers l and m and with 2l+1 degeneracy. What is the corresponding rule for circular symmetry?

Answer (score 1):

If you start with classical mechanics and use polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$, then the angular momentum $\ell_z$ is conserved, as is the Hamiltonian itself.  The only rotation possible is a rotation in the plane, so $\ell_x$ and $\ell_y$ are not defined; $H$ and $\ell_z$ are the only two conserved quantities.

Moving to the QM side of the business, and using the Laplacian in polar coordinates, one obtains
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2M}
\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}\right)f(r)\Phi(\phi)+V(r)f(r)\Phi(\phi)=Ef(r)\Phi(\phi)
$$
using $\psi(r,\phi)=f(r)\Phi(\phi)$ as an ansatz.

Separating the variables, one can solve the equation in $\phi$ as 
$\Phi(\phi)\to \Phi_m(\phi)=\frac{e^{im\phi}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ with $m$ integer by the boundary condition that $\Phi(\phi+2\pi)=\Phi(\phi)$.

This leaves your radial equation as 
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2M}
\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)-\frac{m^2}{r^2}\right)f(r)+V(r)f(r)=Ef(r)
$$
Clearly, the eigenenergy depends on $m^2$, meaning each energy level will be twice degenerate, except for $m=0$.  Hence, if $f_n(r)$ is an eigenfunction of the radial equation with energy $E_n$, 
we have $\psi_{nm}(r,\phi)=f_n(r)\Phi_m(\phi)$ as solutions, and the real combinations
$$
C_{nm}(r,\phi)\sim f_n(r)\cos(m\phi)\, ,\qquad
S_{nm}(r,\phi)\sim f_n(r)\sin(m\phi)
$$
are also solutions with the same energy.

Physically, the 2-fold degeneracy of the $\pm m$ states ($m\ne 0$) is linked to the observation that the Hamiltonian depends on $\hat L_z^2$, so the *direction* of the rotation generated by $\hat L_z$ (clockwise or anticlockwise) does not matter.  For $m=0$, $\hat L_z$ does not generate a rotation and the corresponding solution is independent of $\phi$.